# change facebook input value javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, input

i am trying to create a simple script that let's me create new page auto by filling inputs using javascript.

the problem is that facebook HTML code is very complexe i have the xpath of page name and category inputs but when i try to change  their values i can't.

i tried this code but didn't work for me
`

```
var xpath = function(xpathToExecute, elem = document){
    var result = [];
    var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate(xpathToExecute, elem, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
    for ( var i=0 ; i < nodesSnapshot.snapshotLength; i++ ){
      result.push( nodesSnapshot.snapshotItem(i) );
    }
    return result;
  }
  
xpath("//input[@aria-invalid='false' and @autocomplete='off' and @type='text']")[0].value = "my name";



xpath("//input[@aria-label='Category (required)' and @aria-autocomplete='list']")[0].value = "my category";
```

`

Comment: You are aware that Facebook doesn't allow that. So don't be surprised when Facebook bans you.

Comment: yes i know that thank you